# Outlook: Set a recurrance meeting every 3rd Friday of the month

Tags: outlook, calendar

I'd like to schedule a meeting, using outlook, every 3rd Friday of each month.

As an example:

July 2019 --> Friday 19th
Aug 2019  --> Friday 23th

The first week of August (starting on Thursday) should not be counted.

Is there a way to set it using the default recurring options provided by outlook?

Answer (score 0):

You may set up a corresponding meeting in Outlook manually and then check its properties in VBA programmatically:

```
Public Sub Test()
  ActiveExplorer().Selection.Item(1)
End Sub
```

Don't forget to select the recurring appointment item in Outlook before running the VBA sub.